# Get src of dropped image from event target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have a list of images that i can drap and drop, when dragging starts on image i store it's URL in a state like this:

```js
 <img
    alt="dummy-img"
    src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/c916c9/fff.jpg"
    draggable="true"
    onDragStart={(e) => {
        setURL(e.target.src);
        //console.log(URL);
    }}
/>
```

When dropping it i use that state URL to display the image:

```js
<div
   ref={ref}
   onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
   onDrop={(e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e);
     handleDrop(e);
   }}          
 ></div>
```

But I was wondering if I could use the event `e` produced by `onDrop` to get the URL of the image, without creating another HTML img...

I want to do this to see if it's possible to drop online images directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')` to get the HTML of the dropped image. Then, you can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to read the source of the image, which works both for images on the page and images dropped from other sites.

Example:

```js
let dropArea = document.getElementById('dropArea');
dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault());
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  let src = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html")
              .querySelector('img').src;
  console.log(src);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/c916c9/fff.jpg" draggable="true">
<div id="dropArea" style="height: 100px; background: dodgerblue;">Drop here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution, only thing is that it would have been great if it was and url instead of base64 encoded

Comment: @Marwane If the output source is base64 encoded, then that was the original source of the image set in the HTML. There isn't much that can be done about that. You will see that many images from Google are like that if you open them in a new tab.

Comment: But i also copied an online image on your example and showed me base64

Comment: @Marwane Try right clicking the image and opening it in a new tab. What is the result? What is the displayed URL?

Answer (score 1):

The [drag and drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) in vanilla JS works just fine in React too, by saving the data inside the event when dragging starts. Use `event.dataTransfer.setData` to set a value, and in the drop target,  `event.dataTransfer.getData` to retrieve it. Here's an example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const src = "https://dummyimage.com/200x100/c916c9/fff.jpg";
    return (
        <div>
            <img
                alt="dummy-img"
                src={src}
                draggable="true"
                onDragStart={e => e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', src)}
            />
            <div
                onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                onDrop={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
                }}
            >drop here</div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but my problem was getting the url whitout using onDragStart, only using onDrop . Because i want to drop online images directly